# Creating a zipped Document that containing files from memory stream / byte array in C#

Tags: c#, zip, arrays, memorystream

I'm needing to create a zipped document containing files that exist on the server. I am using the Ionic.Zip to do so, and to create a new Package (which is the zip file) I have to have either a path to a physical file or a stream. I am trying to not create an actual file that would be the zip file, instead just create a stream that would exist in memory or something.  how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Create the package using a `MemoryStream` then.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the save method in the ZipFile Class. It can save to a stream
try this.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
 using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zipFile = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile())
 {
   zipFile.AddFiles(filesToBeZipped, false, "NewFolder");//filesTobeZipped is a List<string>
   zipFile.Save(ms);
  }
}
```

Comment: Vignesh Natraj : where is this zip file saving, what is the meaning of this new folder. if you can give answer asap it will be great help to me

Comment: you can check the method signature for AddFiles,"NewFolder" is the folder structure inside the Compressed Zip file, I am telling the method to put all files inside a folder called NewFolder.

Comment: and it'll save to the memory stream like you asked.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the .AddEntry method on the ZipFile you've created specifying a name and the byte[] containing the actual file data.

ex.

```
    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile();
    zipFile.AddEntry(file.FileName, file.FileData);
```

where file.FileName will be the entry name (in the zip file) and file.FileData is the byte array.